# What exactly 'mount point' means & is this RAID correct?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems

When I install Ubuntu Server 20.04, and I use 3 disks where

- Boot device is 2GB disk (filesystem: ext4, mount **/var**)

and then 2 disks, each has size of 10GB.

Both these 10GB disks are used for software RAID (*md0*), both as *active*.

Problem is as follows:

- When it is configured like this (like screenshot), does that means all data in **/var** are backuped on those 10GB disks?
- If not, how can I achieve that?
- If not and stays it configured like this, does that mean when I will have web in **/var/www/html/** and disk where is web (I guess it is 2GB disk by configuration) and that disk will be damaged all data are *lost* or are *backuped* on those 10GB disks?

*I am sorry if these questions are trivial, but I am new to Ubuntu server (and overall in Linux) and I does not quite understand what mount point means.*

[image: Storage configuration on installing Ubuntu Server 20.04]

*By this (**df** command), I think that **/var** directory is on disk with 2GB of storage which is a little for running website with uploads, etc.*

[image: df command output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody is curious.

It should have been opposite to my question's picture.

So **/var** on **md0** and the rest on 2GB (boot) disk.

And answer for what Mount Point is exactly where *directory* is located (on which disk).

[image: CORRECT RAID (md0)]